How to pass on values when converting a recursive function to an iterative one with stack and while loop
EDIT: My initial recursive code was incomplete, as I did not multiply by f(l, r) the sum of the two recursive branches.
Given a function f(l, r) that computes something from the nodes (l, r) of a binary tree of height max_height, I want to compute a total value by adding values of the left and right node children and multiply the sum with the value of the parent node and pass that along the tree.
I have a working recursive implementation of this, but now I want to eliminate the recursion with a while loop and stack structures. My problem is that I don't know how to "pass on" values during the while loop. That is, I don't know how I should replicate the behavior when I multiply the current value f(l, r) with the sum from the two recursion branches.
I have included two code snippets: The first is the current recursive implementation and the second one is my attempt at the more iterative based approach. The latter code needs more work, and I have placed commented TODOs to indicate some of my questions.
def recursive_travel(l, r, cur_height, max_height):
    if cur_height == max_height - 1:
       return f(l, r) * (f(l + 1, r) + f(l, r + 1))
    return f(l, r)* (recursive_travel(l + 1, r, cur_height + 1, max_height) + recursive_travel(l, r + 1, cur_height + 1, max_height))

where the initial call will be recursive_travel(0, 0, 0, max_height).
Attempt the removing the recursion:
def iterative_travel(max_height):
  call_stack = [(0, 0, 0)] # cur_height, l, r in that order
  handled_stack = [] # TODO: Maybe I need to have something like this, or maybe I need a double array to store computed values?

  # Precompute the value of r_c directly to an n x n table for fast access
  pre_f = [[f(l, r) for l in range(0, max_height + 1)] for r in range(0, max_height + 1)]

  while call_stack:
    cur_height, l, r = stack.pop()
    if max_height - 1 == cur_height: 
      # TODO: Not sure how to pass on the computed values

      # TODO: Where I should put this value? In some table? In some stack?
      value = pre_f[l, r] * (pre_f[l + 1, r] + pre_f[l, r + 1])

      # TODO: Should I mark somewhere that the node (l, r) has been handled?
    elif handled_stack:
      # TODO: Not sure how to handle the computed values
      pass
    else:
      # TODO: Do I do something to the current l and r here?
      stack.append((current_depth + 1, l + 1, r))
      stack.append((current_depth + 1, l, r + 1))
  return 0 # TODO: Return the correct value


As an intermediate step you could change your recursive function to return a single variable only and do the calculations on separate line(s) above. That should help separate the recursive behaviour from the calculations and function calls and make refactoring clearer.

What's your reason for doing this? Why make it complicated when you have something simple and natural already?

May you please provide a minimal usage example to test the in answer provided code against your original recursive version?

I suggest you read https://www.reddit.com/r/compsci/comments/5mpozl/the_number_of_leaf_nodes_in_a_binary_tree_is_one/ in order to see how nodes of a binary tree are categorized and what leaf nodes are (in order to understand my edit of your question).

You speak of a binary tree, but I see no nodes or other tree-like data structure in your code, only integers. Can you clarify?

Can you please answer my question? In one comment you say "for fast access", and your runtime complexity is horrible, so if you're trying this for speed, you're trying to go the wrong way and there's a much better solution.

@nocomment Sorry, for answering late: The recursive approach works well, but its runtime even with memoization is quite bad in the application I am working with. For this reason I am trying to squeeze as much efficiency out of the code by eliminating unnecessary recursion calls. I am aware that I could also switch to another language, such as Rust or C++, but even there elimination of recursion will not decrease performance.

@trincot Forget my earlier comment, it was incorrect: The pair (l, r) of left and right turns from the top does not uniquely characterize a node in a given binary tree itself, since a priori we are not indicating in which order we perform the turns. However, 1.) the function fin both this case and in my specific application depends only on the total number of left and right turns, 2.) I only care about the total sum-product of the form f(l, r) * (f(l + 1, r) + f(l, r+1)), so for this reason no additional data structure is necessary (at least to my naive eye).

Ok, that's what I thought. Except memoization should help a lot. And I don't think you will make it faster by simulating recursion in Python code with your own stack instead of using normal recursion built into Python. Usually that makes it not only more complicated but also slower. I think you would've better asked about the memoized recursive solution and provided information about runtime and max_height, so we could actually do something productive. Looks like the XY problem.

Thanks for clarifying that, @Epsiloon. It corresponds to what I had understood when writing the answer. It would be good to explain in your question why you want to go to an iterative version of the code. Just for the challenge? For time efficiency reasons? For memory efficiency reasons? In the latter cases, what is the input and the definition of f for which you get into trouble?

Let me rephrase: memoization should make it optimal (unless your actual f has some property that allows something even faster). And it makes no sense to try to replicate the unmemoized recursion with an iterative version. To address your actual problem, you need to ask about your actual problem. With enough information to understand/replicate it.

@nocomment I did first try memoization, and it did help a lot. The exact problem I am working with uses this algorithm with one context dependent f and other values which depend on some other given parameters. I unfortunately cannot really give the specific problem I am working with. Having said that, implementation of Claudio's suggested solution (which I was aiming for, but had forgot how to do that -- it's some years since my DSA class) is considerably faster than memoized recursion solution. I have not yet had the time to test trincot's suggestion.

@trincot See also my last answer to nocomment. The memoization of the recursion solution did help at first, but at least in my tests even that is quite a bit slower than Claudio's suggestion. I have not yet had the time to test your suggestions, but I thank you advance for your help!

What is max_height in your real scenario?

@trincot Hopefully as large as possible: Running on my own normal laptop, max_heightof about 16-18 takes in the specific application about one minute with the recursive solution, while the iterative approach takes little over one second for max_height == 100.

BTW, I defined a simple f like 1 + r + l*2, decorated both f and recursive_travel with @cache , and your recursive function responds almost immediately with parameter 30. So I cannot reproduce the efficiency problem you encounter.

Sounds like you've done the memoization wrong. Can't tell/help since we can't see it. No need to share your exact specific problem, you should just make up something comparable.

The job of your recursive function is to calculate a value for each leaf in the virtual, perfect binary tree, and then bubble up such that a parent node gets the sum of the two children, multiplied by its own value.
The base of the recursion still considers one additional level to the virtual tree as it calls f with an increased argument. I would therefore rewrite the recursive function with a base case that is one level deeper:
def recursive_travel(l, r, cur_height, max_height):
    if cur_height == max_height + 1:
        return f(l, r)
    return f(l, r) * (recursive_travel(l + 1, r, cur_height + 1, max_height)
                    + recursive_travel(l, r + 1, cur_height + 1, max_height))

This better shows how each node contributes with its "own" value (determined by f). That means the virtual binary tree is actually one level higher than max_height.
Another observation is  that l and r represent the number of left and right turns in the path from the root to the node. This means that a subtree that has the same l and r numbers as another subtree, will get the exact same value. It would be a waste to recalculate that whole subtree more than once.
Your tree is thus actually more a network that looks like this:
                /\
               /\/\
              /\/\/\
             /\/\/\/\
            /\/\/\/\/\ 
           /\/\/\/\/\/\
          ... ... ... ...

This reduces the number of nodes you actually have to evaluate, making the number of calculations O(²) instead of O(2).
We could turn this into an iterative solution in a bottom up way: first calculate the result for all the unique l-r combinations at the bottom, then for all the parents, ... until the root's value is determined, which is also the end result.
Taking all those observations together we get this code:
def iterative_travel(max_height):
    level = [
        f(left, max_height + 1 - left)
        for left in range(max_height + 2)
    ]
    for height in range(max_height, -1, -1):
        for left in range(height + 1):
            level[left] = f(left, height - left) * (level[left] + level[left + 1])
    return level[0]

Efficiency
There shouldn't be too much difference with your recursive approach, on the condition that you apply memoization. This can for instance be done with functools.cache.
For instance, I invented a simple f and ran with a max height of 100:
from functools import cache

def f(l, r):
    return 2 + l * 3 + r * 5  # Some example calculation

@cache
def recursive_travel(l, r, cur_height, max_height):
    if cur_height == max_height + 1:
        return f(l, r)
    return f(l, r) * (recursive_travel(l + 1, r, cur_height + 1, max_height)
                    + recursive_travel(l, r + 1, cur_height + 1, max_height))

def iterative_travel(max_height):
    level = [
        f(left, max_height + 1 - left)
        for left in range(max_height + 2)
    ]
    for height in range(max_height, -1, -1):
        for left in range(height + 1):
            level[left] = f(left, height - left) * (level[left] + level[left + 1])
    return level[0]

n = 100
result = recursive_travel(0, 0, 0, n)
print(result)
result2 = iterative_travel(n)
print(result2)

This script prints the result in a fraction of a second for both approaches. For larger heights, like 300, the iterative version turns out to be faster, but both still finish under 1 second.

I am so sorry, but my initial recursive code was incomplete: It was missing a crucial point f(l,r) * (sum of the two recursion branches). This changes the problem a bit (at least to my naive eye), and so I ask if you could help me with the corrected code. Coding while being sleep deprived is clearly not a good thing!

Sure, I will look into it. Can you just double check before I do so that your question now reflects exactly what you are doing?

Yeah, I am confident that now the recursive code is what I want (I also fixed the if condition, since we were supposed to stop at a node preceding the leafs, but that really doesn't change much). Thank you!

Updated in accordance with the updated question.

I completely rewrote the answer after your clarifications.

Not O(n) but O(n^2). I also tried memoization without functools and with some optimization, seems a bit faster. I mostly like it for minimizing the cache: storing only results that will be needed again, and popping each cached result when using it.

Yes O(n^2). Corrected.
